# \includepdf moving document into text above

Tags: floats, formatting, pdf, minipage, pdfpages

I've been doctoring on this one for 2 days now, searching forums near and far, to no avail.
The PDF i want to include is 5 pages long and should go into my appendix. I've got 2 lines of text before the first page, that I want to keep there. Obviously I had the common problem of \includepdf starting on the next page and also had to scale the first page without scaling the others. Here's my code example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Appendix}
    \section{Tables}
    \subsection{MyDocument}
    This is a sentence describing the following table in much depth.
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \includepdf[scale=0.6]{appendix/MyDocument1.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
    \includepdf[pages={1-},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{appendix/MyDocument2}
    \label{MyDocument}
\end{document}
```

As you can see i have split the pdf manually into two to enable only scaling the first page and with 0.6 it should easily fit. I have also tried to use \begin{figure}[H] ... \end{figure}, creating the same problem.

[image: This is a small section of the document, however you can see, that part of the headline of the pdf moves into the pages headline]

The rest of the document then moves into the descriptive sentence i wanted to include.
At this point i dont quite know how to fix this problem and would be grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use \includegraphics for the first page, and there is no need to split the pdf, you can select pages both with includepdf and includegraphics.

Comment: With a lot of tinkering, shortening my sentence before the first page etc. I now got it to look great! Only problem being, that it now creates a blank page before adding the second pdf - Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: your example shows `\include` which is for including tex files and doesn't have an optional argument?

Comment: That is absolutely my bad, however the original code is \includepdf, as it should be. Thanks for pointing it out -fixed